# How to update dependencies in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dependencies, synchronization, updates

When I try to `Commit` to Git in Android Studio I get a couple of Warnings about the dependencies:

[image: Git Warnings]

> A newer version of androidx.appcompat:appcompat than 1.4.0 is available: 1.4.1
> A newer version of com.google.android.material:material than 1.4.0 is available: 1.5.0
> A newer version of androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout than 2.1.2 is available: 2.1.3
> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds (junit:junit:4.+)

Right now I have these dependencies in my "build.gradle" file:

```
dependencies {  
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'  
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'  
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'  
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'  
}
```

If I follow the suggestions from the Warnings and change the versions of the dependencies in my "build.gradle" file to:

...appcompat:**1.4.1**'
...material:**1.5.0**'
...constraintlayout:**2.1.3**'

So it looks like this:

```
dependencies {  
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'  
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'  
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'  
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'  
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'  
}
```

I can no longer start the app!

What more do I need to do?

- Install/update these dependencies (how)?
- Resync anything (what and how)?

Comment: `I can no longer start the app!` why not ? is the run button not enabled ? whenever you update dependencies you will probably have to do a gradle sync afterwards, these are just warnings so if this makes life more difficult you can ignore these till you know what you're doing, as updating dependencies is just as likely to give you new crashes or compile time errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching the internet for quite a while and trying a couple of different things, like "Rebuild Project", I found the answer at [Update dependencies - 3. Perform a Gradle sync/reload](https://jmfayard.github.io/refreshVersions/update-dependencies/).

All I had to do after changing the versions of the dependencies in my "build.gradle" file was to **Press the button "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in the Android Studio Gradle Toolbar**.

[image: "Sync Project with Gradle Files" in the Gradle Toolbar]